# Play an audio sound to a specific speaker group on my Alexa when pressing a button

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to get Alexa to play an audio sound to a specific speaker group on a button press.  I have a doorbell button which is hooked up to my Raspberry Pi.  I can detect when the button is physically pressed on the Pi so from here I want to some how issue a command to Alexa to play an mp3 file to a pre-configured speaker group (everywhere).  Is this possible?

The Pi has node-red and MQTT installed so REST Requests are no problem!

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no. The interaction with Alexa is user initiative most of the time. That means, user starts a conversation and then Alexa speaks or plays an audio. The only times that Alexa wakes up on its own is when there is a reminder or a notification (Proactive Events API). The [Proactive Events API](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/smapi/proactive-events-api.html) allows you to send notifications to users of your skill. When your skill successfully sends a notification to a user’s Alexa device, the user hears a chime sound that indicates a notification has arrived. The user can then say, “Alexa, read my notifications” and hear the details.

So, for your use case, it is not possible to wake Alexa to play the mp3 file as result of pressing a button.

Comment: I understand what you are saying but disagree that "it is not possible" to achieve what I am looking for, this functionality may well not be available out of the box but it certainly is possible!

Answer (score 0):

I did what you are looking for by using a routine. Trigger: doorbell press
Action: Music and podcasts:  choose a song in your chosen streaming library, at end of title add group name
Provider is optional if you use more than one service.  Set duration is optional.

Mine plays the first 20 seconds of Somebody's Knockin’ by Terri Gibbs, ends right after the chorus “should I let him in”.